# How to check session value at Blade

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.8, laravel-session

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I want to set a session variable at `cart.blade.php` Blade, like this:

```
@php
    $conflicted = '';
@endphp

@if($conflicting  && ($prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'city_free_delivery' || $prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'country_free_delivery'))
    @php Session::put($conflicted , '0') @endphp
        <p style="color:red;">
           This product has free delivery but it can not be set because of service area conflict of other products 
        </p>
@endif

@if(!$conflicting  && ($prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'country_free_delivery'))
    @php Session::put($conflicted , '1') @endphp
        <p style="color:red;">
           Country Free Delivery
        </p>
@endif
    
@if(!$conflicting  && ($prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'city_free_delivery'))
    @php Session::put($conflicted , '2') @endphp
        <p style="color:red;">
            City Free Delivery
        </p>
@endif
```

Now on `checkout.blade.php`, I need to check the session value of `$conflicted` variable.

So how can I check session value at Blade ?

Because with `get` and `has` method, I can check the session key name.

Comment: Blade views are meant for displaying things not setting variables to use somewhere else. That should be done in the controller.

Comment: @shaedrich I need to do this at Blade

Comment: What's the problem, you encounter?

Comment: @shaedrich I want to get `$conflicted` value by sessions. So I can check if it's value is 1, 2 or 0

Comment: You already mentioned, you can get them by `Session::get($key)`. What do you need us for? Alternatively, you can use `session($key)` or `session()->get($key)` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `session()` helper:

```
@if (session('conflicted'))
    {{ session('conflicted') }}
@endif
```

Comment: Where is the value to check it `conflicted` is equals to 1 or 2 or 0

Comment: You can check the value with `if` statement: `@if (session('conflicted') == 1)`

Comment: Can we also say: `if($request->session('conflicted') == '1')` ?